# How should I play Cammy against a patient defensive Guile?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, street-fighter-iv

When matching up against defensive Guile players who

- Throw sonic boom only from long distance.
- When I get into EX spiral or spin knuckle distance, he just block low and wait.
- Can block or FADC out of rushdown quite well.
- In melee range he just do option-select with random flash kick > FADC.

The only way I can effectively get to him is EX hooligan when he throw sb from afar, but without ICS there isn't much meter.

I tried to use Guile to understand his weaknesses, however, when I use above strategy against Cammy I can win those who has much higher PP/BP than myself. I looked at match videos but these Guile players aren't very defensive, so I still don't know how advanced Cammy players deal with super defensive strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divekicks are your main weapon here. Use them to get over Sonic Booms and gain ground, and then when you're in close use them to bait his Flash Kick or to get in if he's not blocking high. If he has to burn 2 meter to FADC something, that's a win for you. You can use these divekicks combined with crossups to force out Flash Kicks and then punish them.

After you get a knockdown, keep up the pressure. Learning how to add safe jumps, option selects, and unblockables to your mixup game will make you a very dangerous player; you can find guides and videos about this in plenty of places. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=MtWExiRdAR8) is one example of a crossup divekick setup. When you crossup Guile, it's much harder and sometimes impossible for him to use Back-Charge, so after a knockdown you should be trying to do this.

Here are some VOD's of high level players playing the matchup: http://www.sf4tube.com/#guile/vs/cammy . The matchup isn't great for Cammy, but she's a very good character once you've learned how to vortex well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Given the wide horizontal range of flash kick, by divekick bait do you mean cross-up?

Comment: No, you just have to make him think you're coming in. If it's a very patient player it won't be easy, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: That type of player I'm having difficulty with literally does nothing when the distance between us is <= 1/2 screen. Any movement towards him (L spiral, dash, not to mention spin knuckle/hooligan/jump-in) he tries to counter with flash kick and even trade it's his advantage.

Comment: Walk forward, divekick over sonic booms, then you're in a range that's great for you. Block/Throw/Frame Trap as you'd like. If you're facing people who do tons of Flash Kicks, just get into that range and block. You bait it by being in an uncomfortable position for him and then blocking it, not by avoiding it. Watch this match, for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AeVXXXwxyJ8

Comment: I get the idea though this Guile isn't really defensive - at medium range he still throws sb; he didn't FK in situations like 0:19. However 0:38 is a good example of with close range pressure Guile couldn't always anti-air on reaction. Seems I should focus on practicing rushdown.